# how to disable a submit button for 10 seconds after the page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, button

My question is probably simple, but I'm only a week into programming, and I cant really understand the relative answers that I could find. So... need your Jedi help.
How to disable a submit button for 10 seconds after the page is loaded?
Thanks!

Comment: have the button with the disabled tag, use a javascript setTimeout() timer for 10 seconds which after that period will change the button property to be not disabled.

Comment: We can do it by using jquery ... use .hide()

Comment: We can also do it without using jQuery at all

Answer (score 6):

You can use javascript like this

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled="disabled" />
```

using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = null;
      },10000);
    }
</script>
```

The following will additionally show a countdown in a container with ID="timeLeft" if you need one

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var countdownNum = 10;
    window.onload=function() {
      incTimer();
    }

    function incTimer(){
      setTimeout (function(){
        if(countdownNum != 0){
          countdownNum--;
          document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Time left: ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
          incTimer();
        } else {
          document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = null;
          document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Ready!';
        }
      },1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and how to pass it to the button?

Comment: You need to do it in a `window.onload=function() { ... }`

Comment: You can put this function in onload function

Comment: This was fantastic - I reversed it to give 10 seconds to press a button - worked like a charm!